# Change border color input on focus Flowbite React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

I am trying to change the color when focusing on an input in the Flowbite React library, but it's not working. I hope someone can help me.

```
<TextInput
   id="email"
   placeholder="email@gmail.com"
   value={email}
   onChange={handleEmailChange}
   className="flex-1 focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600"
   helperText={<span className="font-medium">{emailError}</span>}
   color={emailError ? "failure" : "gray"}
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official docs [Here](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/customize/theme),

These are the styles that come with it by default

`bg-gray-50 border-gray-300 text-gray-900 focus:border-cyan-500 focus:ring-cyan-500 dark:border-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-white dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:focus:border-cyan-500 dark:focus:ring-cyan-500`

You just need to add a theme prop to the `<TextInput/>` as shown below or make a new file named `themes.js/ts`

```js
const inputTheme = {
 input: {
  colors: {
   gray: "focus:border-your-color focus:ring-your-color ...rest of the 
          styles above"   
  }
 }
}
```

And then import and use it like this

```html
<TextInput theme={inputTheme} ... />
```

**Note: Doing this will actually replace the TextInput Style, it does not extend it, Hence, we have to add the rest of the styles**

Answer (score -1):

You can use useState and make style object set when focus then style set to input

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value,setvalue]=useState({});
  const handle=()=>{
    const dart={
      border: "red",

    }
    setvalue(dart);
  }
  return (
    <div>

    <input type='text' onFocus={handle} style={value}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```